# Allocate unified memory on GPU

Tags: python, gpu, cupy

I am using Python and cuPy to access a GPU cluster (NVIDIA V100, Four GPUs, 32 GB each). I need to allocate large arrays which cannot fit on a single GPU. Therefore, I would like to use Unified Memory using **[cuPy](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.cuda.ManagedMemory.html)**, which can be allocated on all available GPUs.

**My code:**

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np

# allocate unified memory
pool = cp.cuda.MemoryPool(cp.cuda.malloc_managed)
cp.cuda.set_allocator(pool.malloc)

# Desired memory in GB
desired_memory_gb = 42 # SET this value to greater than 32 GB

# Calculate the number of elements required to achieve desired memory
element_size_bytes = np.dtype(np.float64).itemsize
desired_memory_bytes = desired_memory_gb * (1024**3)  # Convert GB to bytes
num_elements = desired_memory_bytes // element_size_bytes

# Create the array with the calculated number of elements
array = cp.full(num_elements, 1.1, dtype=np.float64)

# GPU
print("Array allocated on unified memory...")
```

**Problem:** With the code above, I am able to allocate unified memory and also able to have larger array (greater than 32 GB) but the unified memory is not allocated on all GPUs. In this case, 32 GB memory is allocated on one single GPU and rest is allocated on CPU (not on GPU-2, 3 or 4).

How can I force the program to use all GPUs (instead of just CPU) for the allocation of unified memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cp.cuda.set_allocator for each GPU.

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np

# Desired memory in GB
desired_memory_gb = 42  # SET this value to greater than 32 GB

# Calculate the number of elements required to achieve desired memory
element_size_bytes = np.dtype(np.float64).itemsize
desired_memory_bytes = desired_memory_gb * (1024**3)  # Convert GB to bytes
num_elements = desired_memory_bytes // element_size_bytes

# Create an array on each GPU
arrays = [cp.full(num_elements, 1.1, dtype=np.float64, device=device) for device in cp.cuda.Device.available_gpus()]

# Print information
for i, array in enumerate(arrays):
    print(f"Array allocated on GPU-{i + 1} with shape {array.shape}")
```

Comment: Besides the syntax errors in the code, this is not really what I need. In this case, the arrays are allocated on different GPUs and hence cannot be processed by using a single variable. I need unified memory allocation across multiple GPUs so that I can use a single variable to apply operations (such as dot product, addition).